# how do i stop the cursor position of rotate spin wheel to a particular section?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a spin wheel and it's working fine on random number but i want to stop it on some specific value Ex- 1,2,3,4 ... !

```
$('#canvas').rouletteWheel({
        items : items,
        selected : function(key, value){
        if(key==5 || key==6 || key==7 || key==8 || key==9 || key==10){

        }else{
          alert('SELECTED : ' + key + ' => ' + value);
          $('#canvas').rouletteWheel();
          }
        },
        spinText : 'Click Me',
      });
```

i Have copied the code from this link and i want to customize it . [Reference](https://github.com/JavoByte/rouletteWheel/blob/master/demo.html)